# Difficulty looping over non-ASCII characters

Tags: go

I was trying to complete this coding exercise of searching palindrome strings in a bigger string, but when I run the code I have noticed that the characters that are not ASCII behave differently. The thing is I am just comparing the reverse of the string to the string to establish if is palindrome or not.

```
func main() {
    s := "aaäabca"
    sl := make([]string, 0)
    for i := 0; i < len(s)-1; i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(s); j++ {
            if Palindrome(s[i : j+1]) {
                sl = append(sl, s[i:j+1])
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(sl)
}

func Palindrome(s string) bool {
    copyrev := ""
    for _, valore := range s {
        copyrev = string(valore) + copyrev
    }
    return copyrev == s
}
```

The output is :

```
[aa aäa ä]
```

But it should be:

```
[aa aäa]
```

Comment: `len` counts single bytes, and basic indexing of strings also works on single bytes. But `ä` is a two byte `rune`, i.e. `len("ä")` == `2` and `"ä"[0]` will be a gibberish byte. Many non-ascii characters require even more than two bytes. For loops using `range`-over-strings produce a sequence of runes as the iteration variables, i.e. your `valore` is a, potentially multi-byte, `rune`. You need to take these things into account when implementing the algorithm.

Comment: You can read this article to get some idea - https://golangbyexample.com/iterate-over-a-string-golang/

Comment: Please start with <https://go.dev/blog/strings>

Comment: @mkopriva Thx, very well explained :)